# Java download file via httpResponse spring boot

Tags: java, jquery, spring-boot, http, download

I want to download a pdf file from server in a website. 
When i press a button i send a ajax request to the spring boot server. I create a outputstream of the httpservletresponse and write the file bytes into them. 
In javascript i got the pdf file information, but i don't know how to download them.
I think the problem is the call in jquery. 
I'm not sure if i used the correct content type.

This are the request and response headers of my request:

```
Request-Headers
    Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
    Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
    Connection: keep-alive
    Content-Type: application/pdf
    Host: localhost:8080
    Referer: http://localhost:8080/arbeitsvorratsliste
    Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
    Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3880.4 Safari/537.36
    X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
```

```
Response-Headers
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=44005001.25759.pdf
Content-Encoding: UTF-8
Content-Type: application/pdf;charset=ISO-8859-1
Date: Mon, 19 Aug 2019 07:38:36 GMT
Expires: 0
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

```
@GetMapping("/print.do")
public void doPrint()
{
    final HttpServletResponse response = getResponse();
    RequestUtils.setResponseHeaders(response, "44005001.25759.pdf");

    Path path = Paths.get(settings.getPrintPath() + "\\44005001.25759.pdf");
    try
    {
        ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(Files.readAllBytes(path));

        byte[] outputByte = new byte[4096];
        // copy binary contect to output stream
        while (in.read(outputByte, 0, 4096) != -1)
        {
            out.write(outputByte, 0, 4096);
        }
        in.close();
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        LOG.error("WorkListController.doPrint(): Error while read from file.", e);
    }
    finally
    {
    }
}
```

```
jquery:
myProject.sendRequest('print.do', 'GET', null, null, null, null, null, "application/pdf");
```

```
myProject.sendRequest = function (url, method, dataGetter, onSuccess, onError, onDone, cache, contentType, noAuth, _form) {
var params = {
        url: url,
        type: method,
        data: getData(),
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
    };

    if (contentType)
        params.contentType = contentType;

    jQuery.ajax(params).always(function (xhrOrData, status, xhrOrException) {
        var xhr = (xhrOrData && typeof xhrOrData.status === 'number' && xhrOrData.status >= 0) ? xhrOrData : xhrOrException;
        if (xhr && typeof xhr.status === 'number' && xhr.status >= 0) {
            var json = volante.removeJsonPrefix(xhr.responseText);
            try {
                json = JSON.parse(json);
            } catch (e) {
                // error: json is undefined
            }
            checkResponse(xhr.status, json);
        } else {
            execError('Es trat ein interner Fehler auf.');
        }
    }).done(execDone);
}
```

Comment: This `out.write(outputByte, 0, 4096);` is not correct.  You should use the value that is returned from `read` instead of 4096

Comment: I have changed them, but i have the same problem, that the response data can't downloaded: `int readLines;
            byte[] outputByte = new byte[4096];
            // copy binary contect to output stream
            while ((readLines = in.read(outputByte, 0, 4096)) != -1)
            {
                out.write(outputByte, 0, readLines);
            }`

Comment: There's no way to save a file from javascript once you have it via an ajax request.   Change how you get the file to a simple request, eg `location.href='print.do?...'` or an anchor (`<a>`) with target new window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem, if you want to download a file you must add the annotation @PostMapping and @ResponseBody.
In javascript i have don't call ajax request, but i call form submit.